# How do I make setuptools set the executable bit when deploying some supporting binaries with my egg?

Tags: python, linux, setuptools

I'm using setuptools to create an egg and I would like to include some supporting binaries with it, preferably to be installed in the egg directory.

I can include these files with `data_files` or `package_data` however the executable bit is not set when they are deployed.

Alternatively, I can use `scripts` but then they will (by default) be deployed to a common directory that is shared by all other packages, which I would like to avoid.

How can I deploy these binaries with my package and ensure their file modes are preserved?

Answer (score 3):

The usual (standard) place to put supporting binaries in Linux is in `/usr/libexec`. So you can make a directory under that with the the data_files option. Make the files +x in your source and the permissions should be preserved. Just put something like

```
data_files=[(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'libexec', 'myproject'), glob("libexec/*"))],
```

In your setup function, and a `libexec` directory in your project.

Comment: I would like to keep the files inside my egg directory, so that the egg is fully self contained and operations like deleting the directory get rid of everything, rather than leaving things behind in central directories such as `/usr/libexec`...

Comment: That's what package managers are for. Or uninstallers. Unfortunately, I don't think setuptools supports uninstalling yet. Instead of an egg, you can also build an RPM or dpkg. Then you install that, with the option of uninstalling. This is how software is managed on Linux platforms.